# Removing additional right hand side margins of lists items

Tags: margins, enumerate, enumitem, description

I use `xepersian` package for my thesis. I have some nested   descriptions and enumerates. Is it possible to remove right  margins of items? I have used `enumitem` package, but using

```
‎\begin{enumerate}[rightmargin=0pt]‎
```

did not change anything.

For example please see the attached picture. I have the above enumerate shape and I want the below format.

[image]
Is there any way for removing additional right margins for items of description lists?

Thanks in advance
‎

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage,toc=listof,toc=bib]{report}‎
‎‎\usepackage{lipsum}‎
‎\usepackage{enumitem}‎
‎‎\usepackage{listings}‎
‎\usepackage[extrafootnotefeatures]{xepersian}‎

‎\settextfont[Scale=1.2]{FreeFarsi}‎
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[rightmargin=0cm]
\item
حالت نخست
\item
حالت دوم
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please remove all the unnecessary packages to make your example code truly minimal. AFAICT, the only relevant packages here are `enumitem` and `xepersian`.

Comment: @RuixiZhang I did it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A thorough read of the [`enumitem` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf) is much recommended. In particular, a use of `wide=<length>` would do (page 8). I added some text to show the layout (sorry about messing with your language).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage,toc=listof,toc=bib]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[extrafootnotefeatures]{xepersian}

\settextfont[Scale=1.2]{FreeFarsi}
\begin{document}
\noindent
حالت نخست حالت نخست حالت نخست حالت نخست حالت نخست حالت نخست حالت نخست حالت نخست
\begin{enumerate}[wide=0pt]
\item
حالت نخست حالت نخست حالت نخست حالت نخست حالت نخست حالت نخست حالت نخست حالت نخست
\item
حالت دوم حالت دوم حالت دوم حالت دوم حالت دوم حالت دوم حالت دوم حالت دوم حالت دوم حالت دوم
\end{enumerate}
حالت نخست حالت نخست حالت نخست حالت نخست حالت نخست حالت نخست حالت نخست حالت نخست
\end{document}
```

[image: enumerate list]

More customizations are possible: Use `labelwidth=<length>` to change the label width (page 5); Use `nosep` to collapse all vertical spaces of the list (page 8); etc.

Comment: Thank you, is it possible to do this for description lists items?

Comment: @FahimB Of course! The `enumitem` package is designed to allow users to customize all lists. Again, you should check out the documentation.